# Ignore a specific ip for fail2ban

Tags: firewall, fail2ban

I am using fail2ban with ipfw on FreeBSD. Is there a way to ignore a specific ip address, making sure that fail2ban never blocks or reports it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [whitelisting](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Whitelist) on the fail2ban website:

```
# This will ignore connection coming from common private networks.
# Note that local connections can come from other than just 127.0.0.1, so
# this needs CIDR range too.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.0/8 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16
```

Another reference [here](http://debianclusters.org/index.php/Fail2Ban%3a_Preventing_Brute_Force_SSH):

> First, find ignoreip. It's always important for you to have a way in! These are IPs are fail2ban will ignore - IPs listed here can always have invalid login attempts and still not be blocked. In my file, I'm putting down the network ranges for my internal network (192.168.1.0/24) as well as one other trusted IP address of a machine that I will be able to SSH into if need be. These need to be space separated! If they are not, fail2ban won't block anyone.

Comment: This (like the docs) says everything except *where* to put this line. Some sources say `jail.conf` but my `jail.conf` file includes the line "YOU SHOULD NOT MODIFY THIS FILE". So should this line be added to `jail.local`?

Comment: It can be added to `jail.local`, under a line containing `[DEFAULT]` to introduce the section.

Comment: you can create a `jail.local` file if it does not already exist in the same folder as your jail.conf file